# Combine CreateView with DetailView in Django 1.5

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views, django-class-based-views

In my app I need to create products in a shop. So I have a model Shop and a model Product. I can see details about my shop in a DetailView `ShopDetail`. Now I need a CreateView in order to create products, but the url should be `/shops/shop-id/products/create/`, so I create products inside the shop. I guess it's something like

```
class ProductCreate(SingleObjectMixin, CreateView):
    model = Product

    def get_object(self, queryset=None):
        return Shop.objects.get(id = self.kwargs['shop_id'])
```

Am I on the right track? :-D

Comment: Presumably you have a FK relationship from `Product` > `Shop`, so you will need to set that relationship in your `CreateView` in the background (by getting the id from the url and manually assigning the relationship), then make that field hidden in your new form so that when the user creates a new instance, the relationship will be saved. Alternatively, you could set the relationshop when the users POSTs their form and it's validated.

Comment: Hej Timmy. I know I can handle this in form_valid by settings form.instance.shop before saving form data, but I also have to set context data I guess, so I can get the shop name in the template

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not on the right track: the object returned by `get_object` should be a instance of the `model`; in fact, if you override `get_object` the `model` attribute becomes irrelevant.

There are a few approaches to this problem, but I would myself probably got for a single `DetailView` (with the `Shop` details), and add a form for `Product` to the template via the `get_context_data` method. The form's `action` attribute would, instead of being empty, point to the url to a separate `CreateView` which would handle the `Product` creation.

Alternatively you could simply display the `Shop` details through the `get_context_data`, which is simpler but mixes concerns (as the `DetailView` for shop is defined as a `CreateView` for `Product`).

Answer (score 0):

I think you need:

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class ProductCreate(CreateView):
    """Creates a Product for a Shop."""
    model = Product

    def form_valid(self, form):
        """Associate the Shop with the new Product before saving."""
        form.instance.shop = self.shop
        return super(CustomCreateView, self).form_valid(form)

    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """Ensure the Shop exists before creating a new Product."""
        self.shop = get_object_or_404(Shop, pk=kwargs['shop_id'])
        return super(ProductCreate, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        """Add current shop to the context, so we can show it on the page."""
        context = super(ProductCreate, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['shop'] = self.shop
        return context
```

I hope it helps! `:)` You may wish to have a look at [what the super-methods do](http://ccbv.co.uk/ListView/).

*(Disclaimer: Shameless self promotion.)*